# How to change margin of Textbox inside VisualBrush?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, watermark

I came across this method while looking for the Textbox watermark feature.

```
<TextBox Name="txtBoxName" Width="120" Height="23">
      <TextBox.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="HelpBrush" TileMode="None" Opacity="0.3" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
          <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="Watermark effect"/>
          </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
      </TextBox.Resources>
      <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HelpBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HelpBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

I want to control the margin of a textblock inside a VisualBrush.
If you set the margin inside, it will not change. 
How can you move it? 
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTZ24.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place TextBlock into some container, e.g. Grid

```
<VisualBrush.Visual>
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="Watermark effect" Margin="15,0"/>
    </Grid>
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```

Comment: Call me petty, but the typical container for a single child would probably be a Border.

Comment: Thanks actually this is exactly what i want.
May I ask you one question?

I used this method too, but it didn't work.
It is applied by adding the background property. Do you know what this is for?

Comment: @jskim, the only expanation I have is that such behavior is dictated by wpf rendering engine (which uses direct3d) and *ignores?* empty space. you can probably do some digging in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/VisualBrush.cs,348)

Answer (score 0):

You must add a background to the container.

```xml
<VisualBrush.Visual>
    <Border
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txtBoxName}"
        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=txtBoxName}"
        Padding="{Binding Padding, ElementName=txtBoxName}"
        Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock 
            Text="Watermark effect"
            TextWrapping="{Binding TextWrapping, ElementName=txtBoxName}"/>
    </Border>
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```